# Fastest way to ping a host in python?

Tags: python, ping, scapy

¿Which is the fastest way to check if a host is up or down using python?.

I need to perform ~ 120K pings so it doesn't matter if there is a few of  false negatives.

I have 2 different approaches:

- ICMP requests with scapy
- Execute os.system("ping -c 1 " . ip)

Comment: run both version and check its time - you will see which one is faster.

Comment: why not use something specifically designed for this?  I've used [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/) for years but there might be better tools now.  it has many non-obvious ways of "pinging" --- i.e. not just ICMP pings

Answer (score 1):

Following does a ping and assigns state to host_state Boolean.

```
import os

host_ip = "127.0.0.1" # replace with IP in question
host_state  = True if os.system("ping -c 1 " + host_ip) is 0 else False
print(host_state)
```

With "-c 1" it'll ping only once and return

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be Scapy, because you can send all packets to all hosts at once.

```
from scapy.all import *
packets = IP(dst=["www.google.com", "www.google.fr"])/ICMP()
results = sr(packets)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I'd imagine the best choice would be to go for multiprocessing instead of trying to shorten the ping's time. Here's a nice place to get you [started](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).